# Date format for ics file

Tags: java, datetime, outlook, icalendar

I see an date format for ics file from other article as

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
```

However, I can't understand what I've got from Outlook ics file as

```
DTSTART:16011104T020000
```

Where the year 1601 came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Year 1601 (MDCI) was a common year starting on Monday of the Gregorian
>   calendar and a common year starting on Thursday of the 10-day slower
>   Julian calendar.
>
> January 1 of this year (1601-01-01) is used as the base of file date 
>   and of Active Directory Logon dates by Microsoft Windows.
>
> It is also the date from which ANSI dates are counted and were adopted
>   by the American National Standards Institute for use with COBOL and
>   other computer languages" [1]

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1601

Comment: Thank you. So does it mean do not need to care about year? Can I make the date for every year as 1601 for DST start date?

Comment: @Sanghoon Yes, this is simply the default so any dates you do not change will always be 1601.